# Как убрать запятую в конце

Tags: php

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i <= 20; $i++) {
    if($i % 2 != 0) {
        echo $i.",";
    }
}
?>
```

Как сделать что бы в конце, после цифры 19, запятая не появлялась?

Comment: покуда в целом вы тут знаете, какой элемент цикла будет последним. то сам цикл можно сократить на одну итерацию и элемент вывести вне цикла. это будет самым простым решением

Comment: @teran а зачем его выводить отдельно? Это какая-то отдельная смысловая единица?

Comment: @EgorRandomize смысловые единицы не в циклы заключают, а в функции, например. Зачем - чтобы полностью исключить вопрос поставленный автором.

Comment: @teran по твоему мнению получается что массив как простейшая коллекция не является смысловой единицей

Answer (score 2):

Зачем, собственно, гонять цикл, когда есть `range`?!

```php
echo implode(',', range(1, 19, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, самый дешёвый на число редактирований строк вариант - добавить тернарную проверку на последний элемент.

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i <= 20; $i++) {
    if($i % 2 != 0) {
        echo $i.($i==(20-1)?"":",");
    }
}
?>
```

К слову, можно было бы слегка модифицировать цикл и избавиться от условия:

```
<?php
for($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i+=2) {
    echo $i.($i==(20-1)?"":",");
}
?>
```

Но лучшим вариантом предложу использование функции склейки массива:

```
<?php
$a = [];
for($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i+=2) {
    $a[]=$i;
}
echo(implode(",", $a));
?>
```

Comment: вы считаете что первые два фрагмента кода вообще читаемы?

Comment: @teran считаю, что лёгкая тернарка в конкатенации намного лучше операторов if else. 
Хорошая демонстрация мощи тернарок, в том числе и лёгкости интеграции в готовый код

Comment: сие код ревью никогда в жизни не пройдет у адекватных людей. Хотите использовать тернарный - не надо его тащить в конкатенацию. сделайте две строки для вывода - первая с тернарным отвечает за вывод запятой. вторая просто выводит число.

Comment: @teran не надо оскорблять человека, который больше половины жизни программирует на PHP. Не надо нести чушь. Если такой умный, соизволь показать свой ответ